# add elements to int hashset from int array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, hashset

It is possible to iterate over array and then add elements to hashset one by one. Is there any way to add integers from int array to int hashset without iterating over array elements??

```
 int[] pagesid;//int array
 var deletepages = new HashSet<int>();//hashset 
 pagesid= Array.ConvertAll(text.Split(','), s=>int.Parse(s));
 //values from pagesid should be added to hashset.
```

**Update:**

```
int[] pagesid;//int array
var deletepages = new HashSet<int>();//hashset 
foreach (XmlNode rule in pgmgmtrules)
{
  ruleresult=doc.ParseText(rule.InnerText, false);//parse rule
  if (ruleresult != "")
  { //if parsed rule result has value
    if (rule.Attributes["Action"].Value == "Delete")
    {
      var text=rule.Attributes["pageids"].Value;                                     
      pagesid= Array.ConvertAll(text.Split(','), s=>int.Parse(s));
     //add elements from pagesid array to hashset

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overloaded constructor [HashSet Constructor (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter instead of using the default constructor `HashSet<T>()`.

```
HashSet<int> evenNumbers = new HashSet<int>(text.Split(',').Select(int.Parse));
```

[HashSet Constructor (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the HashSet class that uses the
>   default equality comparer for the set type, contains elements copied
>   from the specified collection, and has sufficient capacity to
>   accommodate the number of elements copied.

**Edit 1** If you want to filter even number from the array then you can use Where

```
var intArr = text.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
HashSet<int> evenNumbers = new HashSet<int>(intArr.Where(i=>i%2==0));
```

**Edit 2** Based on comments. You can use `List<int>` instead of int array. Keeping adding the int pagesids in `List` in the loop and when *loop* is finished add the `List` in `HashSet` through its constructor [HashSet Constructor (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

```
List<int> pagesid = new List<int>();//int array
HashSet<int> deletepages = null;
foreach (XmlNode rule in pgmgmtrules)
{
  ruleresult=doc.ParseText(rule.InnerText, false);//parse rule
  if (ruleresult != "")
  { //if parsed rule result has value
    if (rule.Attributes["Action"].Value == "Delete")
    {
      var text=rule.Attributes["pageids"].Value;                                     
      pagesid.AddRange(text.Split(',').Select(int.Parse));
    }
  }
}
//add elements from pagesid array to hashset
deletepages =  new HashSet<int>(pagesid);
```

Comment: Thanks adil. but i can not declare new hashset everytime as i am iterating in loop and i want them to keep adding to hashset.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar there's no reason to. Just create an IEnumerable with all the elements you need, then create a single HashSet. Eg, if you have multiple texts, do a `Select` over them

Comment: If you are iterating array and want to pass all element then you can pass array in constructor but if you want selective element then first get the filtered array and pass it to HashSet constructor. If you later want to add more element then you can use Add method.

Comment: @Adil:i am iterating over xml node. and then i am getting the elements in integer array . now i need to add the array elements to hashset that i need it after words. i have updated the question. Thanks once again adil.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I suggested to use List<int> instead of int array. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple way from your int array

```
 int[] pagesid;//int array
 var deletepages = new HashSet<int>();//hashset 
 pagesid = Array.ConvertAll("3,5,6,7".Split(','), s => int.Parse(s));
//values from pagesid should be added to hashset.
 var hashset = new HashSet<int>(pagesid);
```

Comment: The constructor accepts any IEnumerable<T>. There's no reason to convert it to a List<T>, you just create yet another temp object without reason

Answer (score 0):

There is no way - even LINQ won't help:

```
 sids = text.Split(',') // It is still array no matter what use
    .Select(str => int.Parse(s)); // This is where the loop over the array actually works

 deletePages = new HashSet<int>()(sids);
```

Because `String.Split` **creates an array in any case** - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But if your create your own streaming string splitter than:

```
var deletePages = new HashSet<int>();//hashset 

 sids = text.MyStreamingStringSplit(',')
    .Select(str => int.Parse(s));

 var deletePages = new HashSet<int>(sids );//hashset
```

Your streaming string parser could look like:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<String> StreamSplit(this String thisStr, char splitChar)
    {
        if (thisStr == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Int32 lastSplitterIndex = -1;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < thisStr.Length; i++)
        { 
            if (thisStr[i] == splitChar)
            {
                 yield return thisStr.Substring(lastSplitterIndex + 1, i - lastSplitterIndex - 1);
                 lastSplitterIndex = i;
            }
        }

        yield return thisStr.Substring(lastSplitterIndex + 1); 
    }
}
```

But there will be only small(if any) increase in performance. So I think that you should stay with your original solution - just use the `HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor.

Comment: i said without iterating over array elements.

Comment: Actually, it's a common .NET idiom for a collection's constructor to accept an IEnumerable as a source.

Comment: But String.Split returns an array.

Comment: Arrays are IEnumerables

Comment: But they are arrays - the array is created, not evaluated. IEnumerable could be processed on demand. If it is what the author mean.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts an enumerable as input. You can write something as simple as:

```
var ints=text.Split(',')
             .Select(s=>int.Parse(s));
var set-new HashSet(ints);
```

Most built-in generic collections accept an IEnumerable as a source so you don't have to manually iterate over the source.

**UPDATE**

From another comment it seems the code will run inside a loop, and `text` is actually the current string to process.

In this case, it's easier to break the loop, create a single enumerable of all texts and then do the conversion eg:

```
var lines=new [] {"123,123","234,456"};

var ints=from line in lines
         from s in line.Split(',')
         select int.Parse(s);
var set=new HashSet(ints);
```

or

```
var ints=lines.SelectMany(line=>line.Split(','))
              .Select(s=>int.Parse(s));
var set-new HashSet(ints);
```

For example the following snippet parses all numbers in a file:

```
var lines=File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

var ints=from line in lines
         from s in line.Split(',')
         select int.Parse(s);
var set-new HashSet(ints);
```